# How to take the first n element from an infinite Generator List?

Tags: python

I have this infinite generator:

```
def infiniList():
    count = 0
    ls = []
    while True:
        yield ls
        count += 1
        ls.append(count)
```

Is there a way to take the first n elements? I mean an easy way, I did:

```
n = 5
ls = infiniList()
for i in range(n):
  rs = next(ls)
```

> Output:

```
print(rs)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: your generator will yield a reference to the same list. What's the benefit of getting `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]` for `n=5`? The approach with `list(itertools.islice(infiniList(), 5))` was obvious for me, but the *design* itself (of initial generator) seems doubtful.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thank you very much for your comment, how would I generate an infinite list with yield properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.islice` does exactly that, though in your example you need to be careful to not repeatedly yield a reference to the same object that keeps getting modified:

```
def infiniList():
    count = 0
    ls = []
    while True:
        yield ls[:]  # here I added copying
        count += 1
        ls.append(count)  # or you could write "ls = ls + [count]" and not need to make a copy above

import itertools
print(list(itertools.islice(infiniList(), 5)))
```

Comment: that prinst [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]] , I edited the question

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero: You can still use `islice` to just select the 5th element.  Give it both start and end arguments (5 and 6).

Answer (score 0):

Just to cover the good answer of @NPE, all I needed is:

```
import itertools

def infiniList():
    count = 0
    ls = []
    while True:
        yield ls
        count += 1
        ls = ls + [count]


print(list(itertools.islice(infiniList(), 5, 6))[0])
```

> Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```